# _.delay() - killing the timer

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Just curious if there is a way to kill the timer in the `_.delay` function in the `underscore.js` library. It is using `setTimeout()` in the annotated source but I can't figure out the actual way to do this.

An example would be:

```
_.delay(this.functionName, 5000)
```

If this has not been called at 3 seconds and I want to stop `functionName` being called, can I kill the timer early?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
var timerId = _.delay(this.functionName, 5000); //save the timerid in a variable
clearTimeout(timerId); //Kill the timer
```

Comment: Cool. Saved me from going into underscore and digging around. :-)